# Sqlite databse table not found while copying it

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have very strange problem,I create a sqlite table with three fields. After that I write code to copy it into iPhone in `-(Void)awakeFromNib` methods of appdelegate class.

Database copying is successfully but table does not exist in the database. I don't not know why it is happening.

Comment: try copying db in applicationDidFinishLaunching method of app delegate.

Comment: Create table programmatically ..it will work for sure !!